# How to collect the name of the CMD tab / window that is executing the Python code?

Tags: python

I run several Python codes in separate CMD windows, so that each one has a different tab name to not all using `C:\WINDOWS\py.exe` I create a shortcut for each Python file I will execute with a custom name and that way I get that name in the window:

> Atalho = Shortcut (PT-BR)

[image]

This way I can filter the list to collect the name:

```python
import pygetwindow as gw
windows = gw.getAllTitles()
filtered_values = list(filter(lambda v: "brasileirao - Atalho" in v, windows))
```

But I would like to create a standard code to use in all my projects where instead of defining the string to be searched, the code itself collects this string for me according to the CMD window where it is being executed, is there any way to do this?